# linux ^C command to kill process

Tags: linux, shell

^C doesn't always work to kill or terminate(involuntarily) the current process (for instance, if that process is busy in certain network operations).

Answer (score 2):

Programs can have signal handler for the `SIGINT` signal (which is typically sent by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), and can even choose to ignore the signal, so this is not 100 % way to terminate a program.

If you want to reliably kill the process you need send a `SIGKILL`, which can't be caught and handled by the program. For example like this:

```
kill -SIGKILL <PID>
```

where PID is the process ID of the process you want to kill.

Answer (score 0):

for conveniences sake, i have a small script called killwin.sh in my path that contains the following:

```
kill $(xdotool selectwindow getwindowpid)
```

bear in mind that any other windows owned by this process will be killed off too